# phonegap choose audio file and upload it on server

Tags: select, audio, cordova, upload

I am developing app with phonegap and jQuery mobile.
I want to select audio file from playlist then upload it on server.
I have google it but there no link that shows to select audio file then upload it on server,
I don't want to record any audio.
I just want to upload audio(that is in my music folder or play list) on server.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
function uploadVoice(fileName, dirName, fileMime, uploadURL) {

var win = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
};

var fail = function(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
};

// file system fail
var fsFail = function(error) {
    alert("failed with error code: " + error.code);

};

var dirFail = function(error) {
    alert("Directory error code: " + error.code);

};

var fileURI;

var gotFileSystem = function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(dirName, {
        create: false
    }, function (dataDir) {

        fileURI = dataDir.fullPath;
        fileURI = fileURI + '/' + fileName;

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = fileMime;

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(fileURI, uploadURL, win, fail, options);

    }, dirFail);

};

// get file system to copy or move image file to
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystem, fsFail);

}
```

Got this from the link [Phonegap - How can I upload an audio file after recording with Phonegap's media.startRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770122/phonegap-how-can-i-upload-an-audio-file-after-recording-with-phonegaps-media)

Comment: Hi @2183115, thnx for reply,but my problem is I want to open a file system so that user can select audio file. If I use your function on button click then what would be the  file name, dir name, upload Url etc. that you are passing in your function uploadVoice. I am little confuse, as I don't want to record audio just select audio from play list or music and upload that.hope you understand .