# Phonegap / Cordova - read file as text from temporary directory

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, audio

i am using the cordova media plugin to record .wav audio samples.

Actually i am able to record them but i can't find the way to get the already created file content.

If i do:

```
// Record audio
//
function recordAudio() {
  var src = "myrecording.wav";
  var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {

      recTime = recTime + 1;
      setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");

      if (recTime >= 3) {
        clearInterval(recInterval);

        mediaRec.stopRecord();
         window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function(fs){
          fs.root.getFile("myrecording.wav", {create: true, exclusive: false},
            function(entry){
              console.log("console loggin file");
              console.log(entry);
        }, function(){
          alert("file create error");
        });
        }, null);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

i get entry this in console:

```
{"isFile":true,"isDirectory":false,"name":"myrecording.wav","fullPath":"/myrecording.wav","filesystem":"<FileSystem: temporary>","nativeURL":"file:///Users/iamuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FC61A8C0-CF4B-4A1C-B22C-D8511B1B1707/data/Containers/Data/Application/716F442C-5076-4C69-9CA9-A1A8C2827898/tmp/myrecording.wav"}
```

but this is not the file content, how to retrieve the file as text from documents:// directory?

The file is recorded using the media plugin into documents://audio.wav path which seems to be a  temporary file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media plugin is by it's description meant to

> provide the ability to record and play back audio files

So I suppose it isn't going to give you the raw data. However, as you know the URI of your audio file, use the File plugin to fetch the data from it.

**Update**

If you want to upload the file, refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770122/phonegap-how-can-i-upload-an-audio-file-after-recording-with-phonegaps-media?rq=1).

If you instead want to get your audio file as Base64 encoded String, refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26534897/1744702).

That is quite a long code and has AngularJS in it, so I took the essential parts as a summary here for you

```
function OnFileEntry(file){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      var image = evt.target.result;
      var base64Data  =   image.replace(/^data:audio\/mpeg;base64,/, "");
      base64Data  +=  base64Data.replace('+', ' ');
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function OnGetFile(fileEntry){
  fileEntry.file(OnFileEntry, fail);
}

function OnFileSystem(fileSystem){
  fileSystem.root.getFile(recordName, null, OnGetFile, fail);
}

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, OnFileSystem, fail);
```

What you need to change here is the recordName to match your src attribute's value.

Is that enough for you, or is there something else I can help you with?

Comment: yes my intent was to use the file plugin indeed... but whats the logci behind, how can i read it in the temp folder?

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to send the file content to Internet, play the audio file, or what? After storing it with Media plugin, it will be stored on your phone's hard drive and can be handled from there any way you want, right?

Comment: i record it then i want to get the content... the file is recorded in documents://audio.wav as tmp file as i see

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow you, friend. So is the question now about how to read the file from file system to memory? I can provide you an example of that if that is the case.

Comment: Please check better the question title, "how to get file content = read a file as text" , and the file is a recorded audio, yes please i need some tip/example i can't fin anything out here :/ thank you

Comment: Ok, now I see your point, didn't actually concentrate enough to title, instead looked at the main body of your question, sorry for that. Now that it is clear, I can edit my answer to meat the question better.

Comment: @safor thank you i will try all this a bit later, thanks a lot, looking forward to accept your answer

Comment: @safor im in trouble i updated my question with the actual code im using, can  you have a look? i don't get how to print in console the file content, it doesn't print aything at the moment :(

Comment: For some reason, the OnGetFile was not on my code summary (though it was available on the link I gave). I added it now to my initial answer. What you are trying to log now, is just a [FileEntry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileEntry), for which you still need to get the content with fileEntry.file and reader. You should be able to use alerts on your application for debug purposes (though something like [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) is easier & faster), so try to see if you make it to the inside of reader.onloadend, where you can alert(image).

Comment: still struggling now i update my question with a new code that seems at least to return all the entry informations, but i am unable to return the file content yet :(

Comment: See my comment about debugging with alerts. You need to see how long you get in the callback chain to be able to think about what goes wrong.