# How to display image and playback audio from Cordova media capture

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to setup the media capture with cordova and ngCordova
After I take a photo and record an audio, which function or attribute should I use to display the image and playback the audio?

I tried the fullPath and cdvfile as image src but doesn't work. Also try to use the image data as base64 data which doesn't work either

Any hint?

$cordovaCamera works

```
   $scope.captureImage = function() {
      var options = {
        limit: 3
      };

       $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
         var i, prop;
         $scope.debug = '';
         for (prop in imageData[i]) {
           $scope.debug += prop + ':' + imageData[i][prop] + '\n';
         }

         $scope.imgs.push({

           src: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData
         });

       }, function(error) {
//        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        str = 'code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n';
alert(str);
       });
      });
```

But I actually want to use $cordovaCapture for capturing both image and audio. I use FileService to return the file path that can be used with 
Trying window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL as suggested but no luck.
So what did I do wrong here?

```
.controller('MyCtrl', [
  '$scope', '$cordovaCapture', '$cordovaCamera', 'FileService',
  function($scope, $cordovaCapture, $cordovaCamera, FileService) {
    $scope.imgs = [];
    $scope.ados = [];
    $scope.debug = '';

    $scope.captureAudio = function() {
      var options = {
        limit: 3,
        duration: 20
      };

      $cordovaCapture.captureAudio(options).then(function(audioData) {
        // Success! Audio data is here
        var i, path, len, prop;
        for (i = 0, len = audioData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
          // path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
          // do something interesting with the file
          $scope.ados.push(audioData[i]);  // fullPath at file:///var/xxxxxxx results in 404
        }
      }, function(error) {
        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
      });
    };

    $scope.captureImage = function() {
      var options = {
    quality : 75,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit : true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 720,
    targetHeight: 1280,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

    var path = imageData;  // this gives /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/91036FB8-4195-4902-99E1-ED943E738DB3/tmp/cdv_photo_001.jpg

    FileService.readFile(path).then(function(result) {

      $scope.imgs.push({
        path: result
      });
    }, function(error) {
      var prop, msg;
      msg += 'Read file error:\n';
      for (prop in error.target) {
        msg += prop + ': ' + error.target[prop] + '\n';
      }
      alert(msg);
    });


  }, function(err) {
    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    alert(err);
  });
    };
  }
])

.service('FileService', [
  '$cordovaFile', '$q',
  function($cordovaFile, $q) {
    this.readFile = function(path) {
      // Reads a file as TEXT
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        alert('onFileSystemSuccess:'+fileSystem.name);  // this is OK
      }

      function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {
        alert('onResolveSuccess:'+fileEntry.name);
// can resolve to "cdv_photo_001.jpg" fine

        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
// this triggers second "Loaded: null"

            alert('Loaded: ' + evt.target.result);
            deferred.resolve(evt);
          };
          reader.onerror = function(evt) {
// this triggers first "Error: null"

            alert('Error: ' + evt.target.result);
            deferred.reject(evt);
          };

          reader.readAsText(file);
        });
      }

      function fail(evt) {
        alert('fail:'+evt.target.error.code);
      }

      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, onResolveSuccess, fail);

      return deferred.promise;
    };
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545601/1744702) but I wouldn't still count it as duplicate. See first my answer there, it should about do it for both images and audio. The regular expression (/^data:audio/mpeg;base64,/) should of course be changed to match your format, for correct MIME types, refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type). If that doesn't work for you, let me know!

Comment: Updated the code in original post. Not working still.

Comment: Seems any file related functions end in error code 5 including createFile / checkFile via $ngCordovaFile

Answer (score 0):

To show the image, turns out I have to use imageData[i].localURL as the src which is cdvfile://xxxx